# Making one input control affect the choices of a second input control

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Using ireport I know how to make input controls but I have one issue that I wonder is do-able. I would like to have two input controls but I need one of them to be filled only by whatever the user picks for the first input control.

For instance, my first input control has 3 categories, from those 3 categories certain choices will need to show up in the 2nd input control's drop-down box according to whatever was chosen from the first input control.

Is it possible to have the choices be filled to the second input control in relation to what was chosen in the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can read about [cascading input controls](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/Cascading_input_controls) at JasperForge.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I googled cascading input controls and this site helped me out: http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/Cascading_input_controls

Comment: @precose: glad you've found it and sorry for broken link :)